# How to call a tagged textfield

Tags: uiview, tags, textfield, nstextfield

I am creating a series of textfields programmatically using tags.  I want to be able to access the data in each text field, but it keeps reverting back to the last tag.

In this example I am creating 10 textfields.  When you click on a field it should turn that field blue, but it always turns the last field blue.

How do I access the field tags so I can get to the correct textfield?

I added NSlog to test the sender #.

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize name = _name ;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    int y = 20 ;
    for(int i=1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
      CGRect frame = CGRectMake(20, y, 100, 30 ) ;
      name = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
      [name setTag:i] ;
      [name setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]] ;
      [name addTarget:self action:@selector(makeBlue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
      [self.view addSubview:name];
      y += 38;
    }
}

- (void)makeBlue:(id)sender
{
    int i = (int)[sender tag] ;
    [name setTag:i] ;
    NSLog(@"%d", i);
    [name setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]] ;
}
```

**EDIT:**
That is great.  Thank you.  It certainly solved one of my problems.  I guess I was expecting a different answer that would lead me in a direction to solve my second problem.  I want to take the input from a tagged textfield to use it elsewhere.  I have the same problem that I am only getting the input from the last textfield.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

int y = 20 ;
for(int tag=1; tag <= 10; tag++)
{
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(20, y, 100, 30 ) ;
    name = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [name setTag:tag] ;
    [name setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]] ;
    [name addTarget:self action:@selector(makeItSo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];
    [self.view addSubview:name];
    [name setDelegate:self] ;
    y += 38;
}
}

- (void)makeItSo:(id)sender
{
int tag = (int)[sender tag] ;
[name setTag:tag] ;
NSString * aName = [name text] ;
NSLog(@"%@", aName) ;
}
```

In this example I don't need to use setTag again in the makeItSo method, but I don't know how to get the value from a particular tag.

Comment: It is the same solution. The trick is to get the reference to the correct view/textfield. After that you can use the usual methods to access the value/change color or do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `makeBlue:`  method you are just re-assigning a tag for no reason. This doesn't change the view. The variable `name` will point to the last view created in the loop even if you change its tag. If you want to access the views by tag use :

```
[self.view viewWithTag:<tag>]
```

So your `makeBlue:` code will look like:

```
- (void)makeBlue:(id)sender
{
    int tag = (int)[sender tag] ;
    UIView *tagView = [self.view viewWithTag:tag]
    [tagView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]] ;
}
```

So for taking the value of a text field you would use:

```
 name = [self.view viewWithTag:[sender tag]];
 NSString *fieldText = name.text;
```

Comment: That is great.  Thank you.  It certainly solved one of my problems.  I guess I was expecting a different answer that would lead me in a direction to solve my second problem.

Comment: Thank you, this is a huge help.

Comment: Ok, one more question.  How can I parse the name of the sender?  If I have 10 tags for 'name', and 10 for 'address', etc, how to I test for if the sender is from 'name' or 'address'?  If it's  a button I call it using [sender currentTitle], but I am using all textfields.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSInteger i =    [sender tag];
```